# Vue search filtering display all items by default

Tags: javascript, firebase, sorting, search, vue.js

I have an issue with my vue app, where I wish to be able to search my items. The problem is that they're not displaying by default, only when a search is occurring.

```js
<script>
import db from "../firebase/firebaseInit";

export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: "Udvalget af urremme",
    meta: [
      {
        name: "description",
        content:
          "Lukrative urremme i læder, reptiler og mange andre eksotiske typer med pasning til Rolex, Omega, IWC og mange andre mærker."
      }
    ]
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Udvalget af urremme",
      loading: false,
      searchItems: [],
      search: null,
      select: null,
      straps: [],
      modal: false,
      sort: "",
      sorters: [
        { title: "Nyeste", value: "newest" },
        { title: "Pris stigende", value: "priceasc" },
        { title: "Pris faldende", value: "pricedesc" }
      ]
    };
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function(value) {
      if (!value) return "";
      value = value.toString();
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search(val) {
      val && val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getStraps();
  },
  computed: {
    filteredStraps() {
      var straps = this.searchItems.filter(strap => {
        if (!this.search) return this.searchItems;
        return (
          strap.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          strap.skin.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );
      });

      if (this.sort == "newest") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
      }
      if (this.sort == "priceasc") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price);
      }
      if (this.sort == "pricedesc") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price);
      } else {
        return straps;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    querySelections(v) {
      this.loading = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchItems = this.straps.filter(e => {
          return (
            (e.title || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((v || "").toLowerCase()) > -1
          );
        });
        this.loading = false;
      }, 500);
    },
    getStraps() {
      db.collection("straps")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          const straps = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = {
              id: doc.id,
              title:
                doc
                  .data()
                  .title.charAt(0)
                  .toUpperCase() + doc.data().title.slice(1),
              price: doc.data().price,
              skin: doc.data().skin,
              type: doc.data().type,
              imgs: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
              colors: doc.data().colors,
              date: doc
                .data()
                .date.toString()
                .slice(0, 15)
            };
            straps.push(data);
          });
          this.straps = straps;
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex px-3 sm8>
            <v-autocomplete :loading="loading" :items="searchItems" :search-input.sync="search" v-model="select" flat hide-no-data label="Søg i urremme" prepend-inner-icon="search" clearable>
              <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                <v-list-tile>
                  <v-list-tile-avatar class="pr-3">
                    <img :src="data.item.imgs" alt="">
                  </v-list-tile-avatar>
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>
                      {{data.item.title}}
                    </v-list-tile-title>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
              </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex offset-lg2 xs3 sm4 lg2 px-3>
            <v-select v-model="sort" :items="sorters" item-text="title" label="Sorter efter" :item-value="sorters.value"></v-select>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>

        <v-layout justify-start wrap>
          <v-flex xs6 pa-3 sm4 lg2 v-for="strap in filteredStraps" :key="strap.id">
            <v-hover>
              <v-card :to="{name: 'Strap', params: {id: strap.id}}" flat slot-scope="{ hover }">
                <v-img :src="strap.imgs" aspect-ratio="1">
                  <v-layout class="grey lighten-1" slot="placeholder" fill-height align-center justify-center ma-0>
                    <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey darken-1"></v-progress-circular>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-img>
                <v-card-title primary-title>
                  <h3 class="text-xs-left">{{strap.title | capitalize}}</h3>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text style="padding: 0 !important;">
                  <p class="text-xs-left">{{strap.price}} kr.</p>
                </v-card-text>
              </v-card>
            </v-hover>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-layout v-if="filteredStraps.length === 0" justify-center>
          <v-flex>
            <h3>Vi har desværre ikke det, du søgte efter...</h3>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
```

A demo link to display the issue:
http://recordit.co/6LauqjrOD4

The idea is to have both the search and sorting options working together, but as mentioned the search function won't display the items on default. This can be seen in the "recordit"-link above, where I've demonstrated the two sortings working together at the same time.

Comment: Your `v-for` is based on an computed array which returns [] while the search is inactiv so its pretty obvious why it doesnt work

Comment: Any ideas on how I can get my items displayed by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this with the computed option to see if the search model is null, and then returning the default straps array, if nothing is applied.

```
  computed: {
filteredStraps() {
  var straps = this.straps;

  if (this.search !== null) {
    var straps = this.searchItems.filter(strap => {
      if (!this.search) return this.searchItems;
      return (
        strap.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
        strap.skin.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
        strap.type.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
  }

  if (this.sort == "newest") {
    return straps.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
  }
  if (this.sort == "priceasc") {
    return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price);
  }
  if (this.sort == "pricedesc") {
    return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price);
  } else {
    return straps;
  }
}
```

},